# Authorize user if request comes from other domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have a user who was authenticated via ***Google oAuth*** through ***OWIN***. After that the user starts a hangout session (pressing the hangout button). When hangout url (hosted by ***Google***) is loaded, it sends an ***Ajax*** request to my web site (via custom Hangout App).

The problem is that the Action at my side is called from unauthorized user.

Is there any way to resolve it and get user authenticated when request happens from other domain?

Comment: are you using app.GoogleAuth or app.GooglePlusauth?

Comment: I use app.UseGoogleAuthentication

Comment: Pleas tell me more about this "custom Hangout App" and the Ajax call. I have been able to authenticate from my app using GooglePlus and after adding the Hangout button, was given access to everything. It's impossible to help you with so little information shared.

Comment: When you configure Hangout Button you can specify the apps that you want to launch. I use my custom application that sends an AJAX request to my web site. The problem is that this request is unauthenticated.

Comment: @Idsa Can you please try with a new basic hangout account?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had time to try creating a custom hangout app (though it sounds kool). I'm pretty sure there's some subtle missing piece like scope setting or registration detail.

Comment: is your ajax call including the bearer token you got from Owin upon Authentication in the header?

Comment: @DaveA, hm... I don't think so. At least I didn't do it explicitly

Comment: You have to do it explicitly. You apply the token in the header of your request. That's wht Owin returns a bearer Token. This form of authentication is distinct from the cookie authentication that .Net users apply within in their own applications. In this case it's the reverse situation -- You are authorizing Google+ to interact with your application. G+ can't be authorized with .NET cookies. It must pass the Bearer Token.

Comment: Even within your own app, if you properly suppress cookies for ajax requests, your requests will fail without bearer tokens. Read about the angular SPA template, it will give you a good idea on how requests and Tokens work http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx

Comment: Also, this introduction to Owin cookies will give you a better understanding of the new architecture and the importance of distancing from cookies http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823263/ASP-NET-Identity-Introduction-to-Working-with-Iden

Comment: And this article explains the flow from external authenticators to Owin, and back to client / browser with bearer tokens for the app. It's kind of confusing if you're new to this, because your Owin app will have tokens for G+, but G+ acting as client will need a token to make requests of your app. There is no "understood" relationship as there is with sessions tied to cookies and browsers http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api